# "sudo: must be setuid root" but already root and 's' permission

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

I accidentally moved my **/lib/** to a different directory which resulted in not being able to run any basic commands (such as the ones in /bin/).

Setting PATH to the new directory didn't work so I resorted to dynamically loading (?) the commands using `newpath/lib/ld-linux.so.2 --library path /newpath/lib /bin/mv`

However, I couldn't move my **/lib** directory back because I was lacking permission. Trying to run `sudo` resulted in `sudo: must be setuid root`.

Looking online, every issue related to having some other sort of permission or ownership of `/usr/bin/sudo`. However, my sudo seems to have the right permissions (`-rwsr-xr-x 2 root root`) which confuses me. I don't have access to `which` but I'm fairly certain that `/usr/bin/sudo` is actually the one being used because it's directory is the first in PATH.

Does anyone know what other reasons could cause this issue?

Comment: If you're running under bash, you can use `type sudo` to figure out which binary it's executing.

Comment: it looks funny... it's kind of like you kill the last chicken and then how you get the egg back.

Answer (score 0):

`suid` applies to execution, and you're not executing `sudo`.

Instead, you're executing `ld-linux.so.2` which merely opens `sudo` for reading.

Comment: @alcathos If you don't have an existing root shell or an existing way of getting one that doesn't need the loader, you can't. If your final goal is just fixing the system, that's easily done from a livecd.